# Should I use data type literals?

Tags: c#, types, literals, primitive-types

For example:

```
ulong someVariable = 1000;
```

The "1000" would be represented as a int by the compiler correct? Would it be a better idea to use...

```
ulong someVariable = 1000UL;
```

As this will avoid casting? Is this something I should even be worrying about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, it's not something you should be worrying about, ever.

in the unlikely case that any compiler produced different code for the two cases, it is pretty much unimaginable that there would be any performance difference worth worrying about. this is the worst sort of premature and unnecessary optimization. it's not worth your time.

fyi, i have confirmed that at least as of vs2012 microsoft's compiler produces the exact same code in both cases.

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.0
IL_0001:  ldc.i4     0x3e8
IL_0006:  conv.i8
IL_0007:  stfld      uint64 ClassLibrary1.Class1::suffixed
IL_000c:  ldarg.0
IL_000d:  ldc.i4     0x3e8
IL_0012:  conv.i8
IL_0013:  stfld      uint64 ClassLibrary1.Class1::unsuffixed
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, is there any reason why? Does the compiler infer the 1000 as a ulong type anyway? Or is it that these types of casts not something to worry about?

Comment: It is more a case of the compiler programmers being waaay smarter than us humble high level developers...

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the compiler will be able to convert the expression on the right to the correct form during compilation, so the value in the IL is the most direct form
 To verify this you can check ildasm or similar. This includes things like string concatenation of literals.

So no, don't worry about it *in this case*. If you were doing something more nuanced: maybe.